# Ran out of input in pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I used the code below, but I got an error **"Ran out of input"**

I had tried many solutions, such as changing mode in `with open(scene_pt_path, 'rb') as f:` to `rw` or add close() after calling each pickle load function. But all didn't work for me.

```py
scene_pt_path = str(kwargs.pop('scene_pt'))
print('loading scenes from %s' % (scene_pt_path))
        with open(scene_pt_path, 'rb') as f:
            conn_matrixes = pickle.load(f)
            edge_matrixes = pickle.load(f)
            vertex_vectors = pickle.load(f)
            scene_descs = pickle.load(f)
```

the output below

```py
loading scenes from gen_files/val_questions.pt
<_io.BufferedReader name='gen_files/val_questions.pt'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-9b71b8a52590> in <module>
----> 1 run_validate(set_params)

1 frames
<ipython-input-16-f964f68cdb2c> in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     93             print(f)
     94             conn_matrixes = pickle.load(f)
---> 95             edge_matrixes = pickle.load(f)
     96             vertex_vectors = pickle.load(f)
     97             scene_descs = pickle.load(f)
```

**Update**

I bring about the detail in this file that I tried to open it

[this file, when opened in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKI6K.png)

[This was when I made this pickle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btmdn.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It sounds like you have a mismatch between what is in your pickle file and what you're trying to read out of it.  But you give no indication of what is in the file you are trying to read.  How is anyone supposed to know why the file you're reading isn't what your code is expecting?

Comment: @jordanm - what you say is incorrect.  You can call `pickle.dump()` multiple times on a single file stream.  As long as you match up pairs of `pickle.dump()` calls with `pickle.load()` calls, the use pattern shown in the OP's question is valid.

Comment: @jordanm, thank you for clarifying this point; it looks like I could separate each with each pickle , and  I think it could be work!

Comment: @CryptoFool apologies for the incorrect info, but it does look like that has happened in the this case. The EOFError indicates the first call to `pickle.load` consumed the entire file.

Comment: @jordanm - sure, makes sense.  In fact, I can see how your statement can be read to be correct.  I was thinking of the general case, obviously.  If your comment started with "in this case", then I wouldn't have said a word.

Comment: @MalodyGamor -  I see nothing wrong with your code.  I have myself used a structure just like that one in the past with no problems.  The issue is that the file you are trying to read doesn't match up with how it is being read.  For everything to work, the file you're reading would need to have been made by calling `pickle.dump` at least 4 times. - If you want more help, you need to give us more information about the input file. Providing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be the best thing.

Comment: @CryptoFool, I just uploaded the pictures that contained how I made this pickle and the data in this file

Comment: It would seem you're only writing 3 things to the pickle file, but trying to read 4. Where did you write `conn_matrixes`?